# 2 jquery's on one page html

Tags: jquery

I want 2 jquery's on the same page but I tried many things like "Noconflict" But I dont get it done.
I am new in website development. Hopely someone can help me.

The website link [Problem page](http://www.cambria-florescencia.com/soorten.html)

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/coin-slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-times.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

With this script is working the coinslider

and with this works the lightbox:

```
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/coin-slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-times.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

I want a pop-up picture below (lightbox). And I work with a coinslider. The problem is only 1 of the 2 works perfect.

Comment: Why don't you use just jquery 1.10 before calling coin-slider.js?

Comment: Remove 1.4.2 and move 1.10.2 into it's place, that should fix everything. You also shouldn't open a new question that's the same as the one you asked an hour ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/coin-slider.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cufon-times.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```